# Insert caption resets numbering of all Table captions to "STYLEREF 0 \s"

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

When I choose a table and choose "Insert caption..." I get the following caption:

> Table Error! Use the Home tab to apply 0 to the text that you want to appear here..1.

After toggling to text it shows:

```
 Table { STYLEREF 0 \s }.{  SEQ Table \* ARABIC \s 0 }.
```

The problem seems to be that the number after `STYLEREF` is `0` instead of `1`. To make it worse, all table captions in the document are affected after this operation.

How can I make `STYLEREF 1` become the default?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following steps (in Word 2007):

1. Go to the "References" tab > "Insert Caption".
2. Select the caption label you want under "Options".
3. Click on "Numbering".
4. Try fiddling with the heading styles and chapter numbers there, perhaps something was corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

Your plan is to number tables in the document with some sort of prefix, a period, then a number.  The prefix would be the text of a heading, for example. But while editing your document, Word replaced parts of those fields.  That is where the `0` in

```
{  STYLEREF 0 \s }
```

came from.  That `0` is not valid; that's where a style name belongs.  The style name is enclosed in double quotation marks. Word substituted `0` for a style name you had specified earlier.  I am not sure why Word does this, but it's happened to me twice over the past couple of years, generally when I'm copying and pasting from other documents with similar styles.

To resolve this, you'll need to replace `0` with the name of the style you intended.  For example, if the style name was the sixth heading level,

```
{  STYLEREF "Heading 6" }
```

Moreover, based on the example you gave, you might intend to include the document's chapter number in the prefix.  For that, you'd specify,

```
{  STYLEREF \s "Heading 6" }
```

substituting the name of the appropriate numbered heading.  You would have had to set that heading up already, a process which is best done in a particular way.  An excellent source for learning about this would be one of the web pages authored by the late Word expert Shauna Kelly (search for them).

Note that I specified `\s` in that second example.  Please review the documentation for the STYLEREF field, where you'll see that this field supports options.  Options are introduced with a backslash, and there are several available for STYLEREF.  You specify these options after the style name, not before.  The `\s` in my example isn't a STYLEREF option; rather, it's modifying the `Heading 6` style name.

Making any such search and replace can't be done using Word's feature for search and replace in the content of the document.  You could use VBA, such as:

```
Public Sub FixStyleRefs()
    Dim pField As Word.Field, pRange As Word.Range    
    For Each pField In ActiveDocument.Fields
        Set pRange = pField.Code
        If pField.Type = wdFieldStyleRef Then
            If InStr(1, pRange.Text, "STYLEREF 0 \s", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then _
                pRange.Text = "  STYLEREF \s ""Heading 6""  "
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

So, I suspect the solution is more than just making `1` the default. It might require more than just changing `0` to `1` in every one of your table captions, but the code provided above will help you do that and more, throughout the document.

Answer (score 0):

I tried several things before finding a solution. The issue is the heading style you chose does not have a numbering scheme associated with it.  Two ways to fix.

A. You can select the style, choose modify, and more in the pop-up window to choose one.

B. If this does not work, find a document where the table caption did work. Copy it, then paste it in your document on top of your table.  Leave table and number be and type the correct table title. Select  entire thing. Click F9.